# Shiny Reactivity- Multiple elements or One element?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to understand how will the below code behave

```
library(shiny)
ui<-fluidPage(
  sliderInput("inpslider","Slider",1,10,5),
  uiOutput("radio"),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$radio<-renderUI({
    x<-input$inpslider
    radioGroupButtons(inputId = 'myRadioButton', choices = c("A","B"),status = 'warning',
                      direction = 'vertical', justified = T)
  })
 }
```

The first time the code runs it will add an input slider and grouped radio button.

Question:- Since `output$radio` block contains the reactive value `input$slider` it will be executed whenever the slider value is changed, So will shiny add a new set of radio button(on top of previous one) every time `output$radio` is executed? or will the old set of radio buttons will be flushed out every time and new one is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the element with `renderUI` each time the slider is `invalidated` it doesnt matter if you press it or reload it...

Comment: So, does this mean that there will always be one set of grouped radio button right?